# Send trigger to onModule that RPC succeded

Tags: gwt, rpc

I have a Class that contain all the RPC.
One of them is :

```
public void authenticateUserCall(String username,String password ,DBConnectionAsync rpcService)
{


    AsyncCallback<UserIdent> callback = new AsyncCallback<UserIdent>() {
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {

            Window.alert("Wrong Username or Password"); 
        }


        public void onSuccess(UserIdent result) {


            Window.alert(result.getUserName()); 

        }





    };

    rpcService.authenticateUser(username, password, callback);
 }
```

If the RPC succeeds, I want to change the layout of the page to the main page for the user.
So how can I send to the onModule that the RPC succeeded ?
I don't want to build the layout in the onSuccess, and I can't clear the login layout because I don't have it on the onSuccess method.
What is the right way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**

A couple of suggestions would be to pass in the AsyncCallback as an argument to the authenticateUserCall. This way the caller could handle on success.

**Option 2: Recommended**

Another option, which will give you much more flexibility is to use the [EventBus](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/mvp-architecture.html) to fire a custom AuthenticationEvent. I use this for handling things like roles. So for instance when the user is authenticated successfully it will return me some information about the user, like their username, password and role. I then use the EventBus to fire an AuthenticationEvent which contains this information about the user. Any of my views and activities can register for this event on the event bus and handle accordingly. So for example many of my views will disable functionality if the user is not an admin. When one of my activities handles this event it will grey out action buttons that require admin access.